# 500 Internal server error while using EF Core with NPGSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying to use EF Core and NPGSQL to perform CRUD operations on our backend database.
While executing POST method - I am seeing 500 internal server error for every alternative requests.

And below is the error I am seeing on the server logs.

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Can't close, connection is in state Connecting
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Close(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloseAsync()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<DisposeAsync>g__DisposeAsyncCore|92_0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.DisposeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|15_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|15_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestServicesFeature.<DisposeAsync>g__Awaited|9_0(RequestServicesFeature servicesFeature, ValueTask vt)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.FireOnCompleted()
```

Also, I am seeing 200 OK response now and then and could see the records being written into postgres DB.

Here is the code snippet I am using to save data into database.
POST Operation:

```
 public async Task postData(ModelInfo modelInfo)
    {
        _context.modelAddition.Add(modelInfo);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
```

I tried to make Add() as async and tried using disposeAsync() method as well and I am seeing similar behavior for all those scenarios.

Any help on this ?

Comment: Do you open close connections manually? or disposing the context manually? And also you don't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` if it's an asp.net core application.

Comment: Probably mistake in outer method if exists. Also `ConfugureAwait` is not needed for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: This method is getting called from a controller. And i have tried by removing the configureAwait() and i am still seeing same behavior.. I+

Also i am not closing or disposing the context.. can you please share any reference to do the same ?

Comment: Show controller method.

Comment: Here is the call being made from controller -

Comment: public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Model Model)  
        {  
            if (ModelState.IsValid)  
            {  
               
               _dataProv.AddRecord(model);  
                return Ok();  
            }  
            return BadRequest();  
        }

Comment: Probably `AddRecord` is an async method and you are not awaiting it.

Comment: Do you need to close connection between each query?  Keeping connection open will solve issue.  The connection pool may be causing issue.  See following for complete list of connection options : https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your code you have an asynchronous method call that is not awaited.  Do a search through your solution for every instance of "Async(" which should highlight all `*Async()` calls and ensure that each and every one of them is awaited. Also check that all methods that are calling these are `async` themselves. The risk is still that if your methods are `async` and you aren't following the `*Async(...)` naming convention, finding un-awaited custom `async` methods will be a pain.